# Sitecore9.3 Index Update Jobs Stuck

Tags: publishing, event-queue, index

We are getting issue in Sitecore Index while publishing.

When we checked Jobs found there are multiple sitecore index and custom index in "running state". And due to this item which we are publishing are not getting indexed however its publishing but not updating web index. 
We also tried multiple times clearing event queue from the database. But not write solution to go again and again and clear event queue.

We have followed below article 
http://pushpendra18.blogspot.com/2017/08/publishing-blocked-or-index-job-stuck.html

Comment: We have used below strategy for CM  <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/intervalAsyncMaster" role:require="Standalone or (ContentManagement and Indexing)" />     and for CD     <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsyncSingleInstance" role:require="Standalone or (ContentManagement and Indexing) or (ContentDelivery and Indexing)" />

Comment: can you make sure that for other custom indexes, you have the same `onPublishEndAsyncSingleInstance` strategy?

Comment: All custom web indexes are using onPublishEndAsyncSingleInstance and custom master index using intervalAsyncMaster

Comment: You can try by removing all the handler from `publish:end:remote`, not sure if any handler is causing the problem. Also, try to review logs for both CM and CD.

Comment: Hi Girish, did you find any solution to your problem? thanks